# Is it possible to put numbers and cut a hexagon?

Tags: mathematics

You have numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.

[image]

It is required to put the numbers in triangles (one number in a triangle), so that when cutting a hexagon into two parts, the *product* of all the numbers in the first part is divided by the sum of all the numbers in the second one.

You can cut through one of the three straight lines.

*Question.* Can you put numbers and cut the hexagon?

Comment: By cutting, do you mean cutting through one of the three straight lines? Also, should the property hold for all three lines or only one?

Comment: @Bubbler, three straight lines are three diametrs. You can cut through two of the six straight lines.

Comment: By *two of the six straight lines*, do you mean that I can choose two lines that do not form a diameter, like the left and right sides of 1 (which makes the puzzle trivial)?

Comment: @Bubbler, yes, you can choose two lines that do not form a diameter.

Comment: If so, it *is* really trivial: I can fill in the numbers randomly and cut out the single 1 (or single 3 for that matter) because 1 divides 20 (and 3 divides 18).

Comment: @Bubbler, of course you cut out the single 1 or 3, but in my question I wrote "sum of all the numbers...". Where is sum in your comment?

Comment: This problem seems like something a math teacher might use as a tool for teaching the concept of divisibility at grade school. Certainly there is no puzzle of any kind involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to do:

> One option is to place 1, 2, and 4 in one group, and 3, 5, and 6 in the other. Then the sums are 7 and 14, and 14 evenly divides into 7.
>
>  The only actual constraint in finding a solution is that the smaller group must sum to 1, 3, or 7. This is easily satisfied.

Comment: I am sorry, in my question after your answer, I encountered a bug. Instead of "the sum of all the numbers in the first part" should be "the product of all the numbers in the first part"